# AWS EFS alternatives for Mumbai region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to set up an NFS share in Mumbai region. AWS doesn't provide support of EFS in this region? What are the possible alternatives if I am using AMI Linux? I tried a Samba, but it was very complicated to set it up. I haven't seen any good reviews for Gluster FS. SoftNAS is very expensive. What are the other options left for me?

Comment: Most common Linux distributions come with NFS capabilities built-in/enabled already, and usually only require a package install and configuration to get something working. Unless you have some specific use case, you don't need to explore alternative/commercial offerings.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nfs share option. Below is a very simple article on how to get this done.

- **Step 1** :  Ensure that You allow Inbound connections from 0.0.0.0/0 to TCP Ports 111,2049,32768,44182,54508
- **Step 2** :  Ensure that You allow Inbound connections from 0.0.0.0/0 to UDP Ports 111,2049,32768,32770-32800
- **Step 3** : Install NFS Server using below command
- ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
  ```

  **Step 4** : Add the details of folder which you want to share / access from all other EC2 instances to "*/etc/exports*". Eg: If the folder you want to share is "/folder_to_share", then add a line to "*/etc/exports*" file like below:

  ```
  /folder_to_share *(rw,no_subtree_check,sync,insecure)
  ```
- **Step 5** : Reload NFS Server Service using below command

  ```
   sudo service nfs-kernel-server reload
  ```
- **Step 6** : On your client, install client utils for accessing the shared folder

  ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nfs-common
  ```
- **Step 7** : Make mount point & mount the shared folder on the client instance using below command

  ```
   mkdir /shared_folder
   mount -t nfs <private_ip_of_first_instance>:/folder_to_share /shared_folder
  ```